# How to install ProxyChainsGUI

Tags: 12.04, installation, networking, proxy

I have successfully installed proxychains and it is working fine so far. My only problem is that I do not know how to get the GUI to work/install it, which I got from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/proxychainsgui/
I have also of course done some research of my own and I only found this: http://sourceforge.net/p/proxychainsgui/discussion/1151374/thread/a138aedd/ which unfortunately did not work for me. I have already tried executing it by clicking it (once choosing simply to "execute" it and once to "run it in terminal") and nothing happened. Trying to execute it in a terminal (via command this time to see if it gives me any errors) it only gave me an error message, saying that the file is not an executable script.

Any help with this would be very appreciated!

Comment: You most likely mean that you need to compile the program. Go back to that forum thread, follow the instructions, and post the errors back here. Then we can tell you what is wrong.

Comment: After retrying it using the same version I got another parse error. Then I tried the older version and it finally worked out. Thanks nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

You should give it an executable bit. To do so, run from the directory contains it:

```
chmod +x ProxyChainsGUI
```

and then just execute it.